# Strip all images from a PDF

Tags: gratis, pdf

There are lots of programs to extract the images, but what I want is an imageless PDF.

Not too difficult to operate, no manual intervention such as repeatedly finding images and deleting them then saving to a new document.

Just a program to which I can give the name of a file (or directory) and end up with imageless PDF files.

Command line or GUI doesn't matter.

Comment: Does a .net library and a sample application that shows how to implement your request qualify as a solution?

Comment: +1 for asking. Short answer, I don't know until I see it. I use Embarcadero's Delphi, and was hoping for a VCL component. However, Delphi supports .NEtT(I just didn't try it yet).  If you post it as an answer to my followup "ok, I'll code it myself" question, it will get upvoted for sure. I will leave this question open in case someone can point out an existing application. For coding, please see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18842/vcl-component-to-manipulate-pdf-files  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the format to be preserved, this can be done easily.

Use Foxit reader. Do a save as Text file.

Now use a free pdf printer like foxit printer or cutepdf to print into pdf files.

### Edit: for preserving paragraph format

I did a google search and found that a freeware A-PDF extractor(http://www.a-pdf.com/text/download.htm) has this capability.

See the image below. I have shown the pdf and extracted text file side-by-side. Hope this is what you were looking for. :)

[image: PDF XChange Viewer and Notepad++ Windows]

Comment: Weeeeell,  .... it does work. BUT, the formatting leaves a lot to be desired. Paragraphs are being split into multiple lines, with blank lines between them. Do you know  of any way to format that correctly?

Comment: I have edited the answer with what I think is the solution for the benefit of someone else who may have this problem.

Comment: Fantastic!  ok, now here are a few fewer blank lines than I might like, but it is certainly good enough to read Welcome aboard. A great first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can use the library [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/):

- open source (Apache License v2.0)
- [can remove all images/drawings from a PDF file and leave text only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6831194/395857)

[image: Apache PDFBox]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the draft option of [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/):

```
cpdf -draft in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

Answer stolen from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702568/40961

Comment: And I thought that I had searched well before asking ;-)  Thnaks

Answer (score -1):

Consider this link, it will help you

http://www.pdfaid.com/ExtractImages.aspx

Features

- In addition, this tool provides you to save your images in the format
  like jpg, gif, png, or bmp.
- Once you are done with format selection, then you can also give the
  number to the image so that you can relate the images back to the
  document.( it's only your wish)

You can achieve all this with the single click only as what you are looking for.

You can also try this online tool to perform your task. Best part is that, there is no installation required for this tool. It’s completely free.

http://www.extractpdf.com/

Comment: This does not do what I asked for. Please read the question again.  Yes, it takes images out of PDF, in the sense that it let's you extract them & store them somewhere. BUT, the original PDF is still unchanged. I want to take images out of a PDF in the sense of REMOVE them. leaving behind a PDF with no images.